# oracle find last row in table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-limit

hey i have an database project and i want to get the last row from my table gadgets, for the first row i wrotte this and it worked

```
SELECT *
  from Gadgets
where ROWNUM =1
```

but for the last index for example 100 it doesn't work

```
SELECT *
  from Gadgets
where ROWNUM =100
```

how i have to writte my comand that i will work, i work on oracle

Comment: `rownum = 1` does not give the "first row in the table", whatever that means. It gives the first row to be returned by the query, and that will depend on how the data is physically stored and how optimiser decides to execute the query.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a "first" or "last" row in the table.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets (technically multi-sets because duplicates are allowed).  You need an `order by`.

If you have an incremental id or created date, then you can use that to define "first" or "last".  For the "first" row:

```
select t.*
from t
order by <ordering column>
fetch first 1 row only;
```

And for the "last" row:

```
select t.*
from t
order by <ordering column> desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: is odering the number that i want to ?

Comment: `<ordering column>` is however you are defining "first" and "last".